# Where can you buy a Windows Server 2003 Terminal Service license?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, licensing

Only place I really could find was ebay and Amazon... both seemed a bit sketchy. I just need two.. It needs to be per-device as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exercise your [downgrade rights on Server 2008 Terminal Server Licenses](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/downgrade-rights.aspx). So buy a 2008 license, call up Microsoft and get them to re-issue it as a 2003 license.

[This page here](http://ts.veranoest.net/ts_faq_licensing.htm#downgrade) has some interesting information on the topic (especially if you're running 2003 R2).